# Creating matrix table grouped by columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have requirement where I need to list all the projects running inside a specific region. All the project should be added as columns in a table. The number of projects can increase so the table needs to be dynamically created having dynamic columns. Also the table should start with two columns which include information about the category and region which should be repeated for every project. Also we need to group the project by status. So we need column grouping. I don't know whether the below JSON structure is accurate to meet the requirements or do we need to change that

I have JSON similar to this,

```
[{
  "category": "a",
  "region": "Region 1",
  projects: [{
    "project": "A",
    "resources" : 2,
    "status": green
  }, {
    "project": "B", 
    "resources" : 2,
    "status": green
  }, {
    "project": "C",
    "resources" : 2,
    "status": green
  }]
}, {
  "category": "b",
  "region": "Region 2",
  projects: [{
    "project": "F",
    "resources" : 2,
    "status": red
  }, {
    "project": "A",
    "resources" : 4,
    "status": green
  }]
}]
```

Is it possible to dynamically create a table grouped by status column.
Or should we handle creation of such tables from server side.
The table should look similar to this,

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Category</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Region</th>
    <th colspan="4">Green</th>
    <th colspan="3">Red</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
    <th>E</th>
    <th>F</th>
    <th>G</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Region 1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Region 2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

I want whether this can be achieved dynamically via jQuery using the above JSON structure or do we need to modify the JSON structure.

Comment: You can certainly perform any data transformations using javascript in-browser and I would be willing to show you how but I don't understand your table structure at all. Please clarify

Comment: thanks for the reply I will try to add more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in JavaScript using a function such as

```
"use strict";

function groupBy(array, selectKey) {
  return array.reduce((groups, element) => {
      const key = selectKey(element);
      if (groups[key]) {
        groups[key].push(element);
      } 
      else {
        groups[key] = [element];
      }

      return groups;
    }, {});
}
```

This will project an array into an object with properties for each distinct key projected from the objects in the array. The value of each property will be an array of the values that produced that key under whatever `selectKey` function we passed.

*Note: `selectKey` should return a string or a number and, irregardless, its result will be coerced into a string.*

Now, given your array, we can group it.

Lets start by grouping by `category`:

```js
"use strict";

function groupBy(array, selectKey) {
  return array.reduce((groups, element) => {
      const key = selectKey(element);
      if (groups[key]) {
        groups[key].push(element);
      } 
      else {
        groups[key] = [element];
      }
      
      return groups;
    }, {});
}

const xs = [{
  "category": "a",
  "region": "Region 1",
  projects: [{
    "project": "A",
    "resources": 2,
    "status": 'green'
  }, {
    "project": "B",
    "resources": 2,
    "status": 'green'
  }, {
    "project": "C",
    "resources": 2,
    "status": 'green'
  }]
}, {
  "category": "b",
  "region": "Region 2",
  projects: [{
    "project": "F",
    "resources": 2,
    "status": 'red'
  }, {
    "project": "A",
    "resources": 4,
    "status": 'green'
  }]
}];

const byCategory = groupBy(xs, x => x.category);

console.log(byCategory);
```

Now, what if we need to group by multiple columns? We could augment groupBy with logic to take a custom comparison function, but we can cheat by using string concatenation.

In the following example, we group by `category` *and* by `region`:

```js
"use strict";

function groupBy(array, selectKey) {
  return array.reduce((groups, element) => {
      const key = selectKey(element);
      if (groups[key]) {
        groups[key].push(element);
      } 
      else {
        groups[key] = [element];
      }
      
      return groups;
    }, {});
}

const xs = [{
  "category": "a",
  "region": "Region 1",
  projects: [{
    "project": "A",
    "resources": 2,
    "status": 'green'
  }, {
    "project": "B",
    "resources": 2,
    "status": 'green'
  }, {
    "project": "C",
    "resources": 2,
    "status": 'green'
  }]
}, {
  "category": "b",
  "region": "Region 2",
  projects: [{
    "project": "F",
    "resources": 2,
    "status": 'red'
  }, {
    "project": "A",
    "resources": 4,
    "status": 'green'
  }]
}];

const byCategoryAndRegion = groupBy(
    xs,
    x => `category: ${x.category}, region: ${x.region}`
  );

console.log(byCategoryAndRegion);
```

I'm not entirely clear on the structure and orientation of your data, but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we use this code to group columns which are present in the inner array i.e projects array

Comment: Yes, you can use any projection you want. For example: `groupBy(xs, x => x.projects.map(p => p.status).join(' '));` Groups the top level array items but the concatenation of their status values (I assume status is a string).

Comment: The tricky part would be parsing the key string as it gets more complex. At some point we might need a more complex implementation using UUIDs and an extra function to select a comparison value from a key that is an arbitrary object. If we have access to the native ES2015 `Map`, we can do it trivially.

Comment: thanks, it worked. I would like to learn more about such transformations. Can you point me to some good resources ?

Comment: There is a fair amount of literature about this. It is sometimes called *"Functional JavaScript"* but it is a hybrid of functional and object oriented approaches. You should most definitely read the still relevant [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742). Some interesting reading on this particular topic can be found in this sixth chapter of [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html) which is available online. I don't agree with all of the latter book but that chapter is well worth reading.